# permanent error in processing during lookup of my@domain.com: 23.83.214.30 not found

Tags: email, spf

Here is the error upon receiving the email using domain's email account.

> Received-SPF: permerror (google.com: permanent error in processing during lookup of email@domain.com: 23.83.214.30 not found) client-ip=46.232.183.183;
>   Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
>          spf=permerror (google.com: permanent error in processing during lookup of email@domain.com: 23.83.214.30 not found) smtp.mailfrom=email@domain.com

My SPF record `v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:119.81.160.218 ~all`

Also, everytime I use the domain's email account for sending an email, red question mark appears instead of profile photo.

**Mail Header**

```
Delivered-To: googol8080@gmail.com
Received: by 10.237.36.7 with SMTP id r7csp126644qtc;
Tue, 29 Nov 2016 22:02:10 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.99.97.15 with SMTP id v15mr57306605pgb.10.1480485730049;
Tue, 29 Nov 2016 22:02:10 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: info@mydomain.com
Received: from caracal.maple.relay.mailchannels.net (caracal.maple.relay.mailchannels.net. [23.83.214.30])
by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id n23si62876213pfj.268.2016.11.29.22.02.09
for googol8080@gmail.com
(version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
Tue, 29 Nov 2016 22:02:09 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning info@mydomain.com does not designate 23.83.214.30 as permitted sender) client-ip=23.83.214.30;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning info@mydomain.com does not designate 23.83.214.30 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=info@mydomain.com
X-Sender-Id: iconceptglobal|x-authuser|info@mydomain.com
Received: from relay.mailchannels.net (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by relay.mailchannels.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id B64ACA1BCB for googol8080@gmail.com; Wed, 30 Nov 2016 06:02:08 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from virgo.zoom.ph (ip-10-220-3-24.us-west-2.compute.internal [10.220.3.24]) by relay.mailchannels.net (Postfix) with ESMTPA id E1923A1B5A for googol8080@gmail.com; Wed, 30 Nov 2016 06:02:07 +0000 (UTC)
X-Sender-Id: iconceptglobal|x-authuser|info@mydomain.com
Received: from virgo.zoom.ph (virgo.zoom.ph [10.135.9.54]) (using TLSv1.2 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384) by 0.0.0.0:2500 (trex/5.7.8); Wed, 30 Nov 2016 06:02:08 +0000
X-MC-Relay: Neutral
X-MailChannels-SenderId: iconceptglobal|x-authuser|info@mydomain.com
X-MailChannels-Auth-Id: iconceptglobal
X-MC-Loop-Signature: 1480485728226:2615264436
X-MC-Ingress-Time: 1480485728225
Received: from mail-qk0-f182.google.com ([209.85.220.182]:36094) by virgo.zoom.ph with esmtpsa (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128) (Exim 4.87) (envelope-from info@mydomain.com) id 1cBxy1-0039B0-B0 for googol8080@gmail.com; Wed, 30 Nov 2016 14:02:05 +0800
Received: by mail-qk0-f182.google.com with SMTP id n21so199451019qka.3
for googol8080@gmail.com; Tue, 29 Nov 2016 22:02:05 -0800 (PST)
X-Gm-Message-State: AKaTC006YjUcZeXcUWOAt54A5wUa8rCXBzJ8gUk0m+pMQGDZfts+vWKgpBxUOFo/doXcTJ4bJSm1Bx1fAhtHkA==
X-Received: by 10.55.190.1 with SMTP id o1mr26726008qkf.305.1480485724145; Tue, 29 Nov 2016 22:02:04 -0800 (PST)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.12.166.154 with HTTP; Tue, 29 Nov 2016 22:02:03 -0800 (PST)
From: Domain - Information info@mydomain.com
Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2016 14:02:03 +0800
X-Gmail-Original-Message-ID: CADgT1k-wWwduro7GgqsmpqnFG8TT21dO88kc9YkeXYHSqGzFuw@mail.gmail.com
Message-ID: CADgT1k-wWwduro7GgqsmpqnFG8TT21dO88kc9YkeXYHSqGzFuw@mail.gmail.com
Subject: asdasd
To: googol8080@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=94eb2c0438a4aed2e205427e7198
X-AuthUser: info@mydomain.com

--94eb2c0438a4aed2e205427e7198
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

asdasd

--94eb2c0438a4aed2e205427e7198
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
asdasd

--94eb2c0438a4aed2e205427e7198--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

23.83.214.30 is the IP address of MailChannels SMTP relay service. If you are using a relay service, you will need to include them in your SPF record.

The SPF record for your-domain.com should include IPs of any servers sending mail on its behalf. See https://mailchannels.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200262610-SPF-Records-Configuration-for-MailChannels-Cloud for configuration information.

It's possible these IP addresses are already included, but it's not possible to tell from what you listed. Your current SPF record includes the A records for your-domain.com, the IPs/servers found through MX records of your-domain.com and the IP address '119.81.160.218' (presumably your server, but this is likely the same as the A record).

Posting full mail headers and your domain name would be helpful in verifying how records are setup.

Comment: I will post the mail headers